# Function not returning proper value, looking for a value in a list

Tags: java

I have a class that has a function like this:

```
public void createFlight(String aname, String orig, String dest, String id) {
    Flight f = new Flight(aname, orig, dest, id);
    boolean found = false;
    boolean quit = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < flightList.size(); i++) {
        //Check origin exist
        if (airportList.get(i).getName().equals(orig))
            found = true;
        if (!found) {
            System.out.println("Origin " + orig + " does not exist.");
            quit = true;
        }
        found = false;
        //check destination exists
        if (airportList.get(i).getName().equals(dest))
            found = true;
        if (!found) {
            System.out.println("Destination " + dest + " does not exist.");
            quit = true;
        }
        //check if origin and destination are the same
        if (orig.equals(dest)) {
            System.out.println(id + "'s Origin and destination cannot be the same.");
            quit = true;
        }
    }
    if (!quit) {
        flightList.add(f);
        System.out.println("Added flight " + id);
    }
}
```

If I run:

```
    s.createFlight("USAIR", "ACE", "YVR", "778");//origin airport does not exist
    s.createFlight("BOS", "YHZ", "YUL", "123");
```

Line 2 should work correctly, and line 1's origin airport does not exist. However I get this:

```
Added flight 778
Destination YUL does not exist.
```

Which is the incorrect output. My expected output would say the first flight's origin does not exist.

Comment: What is `Flight`? What is `airportList`? What is `flightList`?

Comment: This logic is really odd...

Comment: They are a list of airport and flight objects.

Comment: @JasonC Agreed, its almost like the assumption that the airport list is as long as the flightlist

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what is what, but the loop variable "i" should be running from 0 to airPortList.size() i think.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset `found` to `false` at the start of the loop just before checking if the origin exists; otherwise it might have a value of `true` left over from the previous iteration's destination check.

```
for (int i = 0; i < flightList.size(); i++) {
    found = false; // <-- add this
    //Check origin exist
    if (airportList.get(i).getName().equals(orig))
        found = true;
    ...
```

With the way you have it now, when iterating through the flight list, if one flight's destination exists, it behaves as if the *next* flight's origin exists, regardless of whether it actually does or not.

This logic is a bit odd overall, however, and some simplification (such as [Mohammad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22418223/616460)) could make it a little clearer and make it easier to diagnose problems like this. Also, like [R Kaja Mohideen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22418204/616460)'s answer mentioned, you may not be searching the whole airport list.

Comment: @KevinBowersox Definitely. The use of e.g. a `Set` to store known airports would be a good first step in that direction.

Answer (score 1):

Does this simplification help at all? Can you figure out what u're doing wrong?

```
public void createFlight(String aname, String orig, String dest, String id) {
    Flight f = new Flight(aname, orig, dest, id);
    boolean found = false;
    boolean quit = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < flightList.size(); i++) {
        //Check origin exist
        if (!airportList.get(i).getName().equals(orig))
        {
            System.out.println("Origin " + orig + " does not exist.");
            quit = true;
        }        
        //check destination exists
        if (!airportList.get(i).getName().equals(dest))
        {
            System.out.println("Destination " + dest + " does not exist.");
            quit = true;
        }
        //check if origin and destination are the same
        if (orig.equals(dest)) {
            System.out.println(id + "'s Origin and destination cannot be the same.");
            quit = true;
        }
    }
    if (!quit) {
        flightList.add(f);
        System.out.println("Added flight " + id);
    }
}
```

---

Here's what you can do:

```
public void createFlight(String aname, String orig, String dest, String id) {
    Flight f = new Flight(aname, orig, dest, id);
    boolean found = false;
    boolean quit = false;


    for (int i = 0; i < flightList.size(); i++) {
        //Check origin exist
        if (!airportList.get(i).getName().equals(orig))
        {
            System.out.println("Origin " + orig + " does not exist.");
            quit = true;
            break;
        }        
        //check destination exists
        else if (!airportList.get(i).getName().equals(dest))
        {
            System.out.println("Destination " + dest + " does not exist.");
            quit = true;
            break;
        }
        //check if origin and destination are the same
        else if (orig.equals(dest)) {
            System.out.println(id + "'s Origin and destination cannot be the same.");
            quit = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!quit) {
        flightList.add(f);
        System.out.println("Added flight " + id);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a good simplification, and it removes the root issue I described in my answer.

Comment: I'm sorry I still don't see where I'm going wrong. Could you elaborate?

Comment: You are iterating through the list which CONTAINS your origin flight. You should skip this record. I'll update the code to reflect what you should do.

Answer (score 1):

The `for loop` is iterating through all of the `Flight`s in the `flightList` instead of all of the `Airport`s in the `Airport` list.

If there are three flights in the `flightList` and 100 `Airport`s in the `airportList` the logic in the loop will only compare the provided flight against the first 3 airports instead of all 100.  You should use `airportList` to determine the number of iterations, or better yet put the `Airport`s within a `Map<String,Airport>` where the key is the airport code.  This will eliminate many of the flags in the code and make the conditionals more concise.

```
Map<String,Airport> airportMap = new HashMap<String,Airport>();
/* Populate map like airportMap.put("BOS", new Airport("BOS",..));*/

public void createFlight(String aname, String orig, String dest, String id) {

    if(airportMap.containsKey(orig) && airportMap.containsKey(dest) && !orig.equals(dest)){
         Flight f = new Flight(aname, orig, dest, id);
         flightList.add(f);
         System.out.println("Added flight " + id);
    }else if(orig.equals(dest)){
         System.out.println(id + "'s Origin and destination cannot be the same.");
    }else if(!airportMap.containsKey(orig)){
         System.out.println("Origin " + orig + " does not exist.");
    }else if(!airportMap.containsKey(dest)){
         System.out.println("Destination " + dest + " does not exist.");
    }   
}
```